# Add a way to highlight/emphasize changes in code

Tags: feature-request, markdown, code-formatting, code, code-block

Answers to coding questions often use a minor change to the example code. But because it's code, you cant emphasize those differences with markdown syntax.

See example below where I've done some gymnastics to show a diff:

---

### Example Question

Why isn't his working?

```html
<htwl>
<body>
    document
</body>
</html>
```

### Example Answer

Ah, just a typo. You meant:

> <del><htwl></del>
>   **<html>**
>       <body>
>           document
>       </body>
>   </html>

---

In the above example answer, I used a quote block instead of code block, and  `<del>` to strikeout the old line, and HTML character entities (including `&nbsp;` for indentation) to make sure the HTML didn't render as HTML. Painful.

I don't necessarily need to see a full diff, (as in git) where the old line is red and in ~strikeout~ and the new line is green. But it would be nice to give some sort of indication *within a code block* to emphasize or hi-light a particular change, to focus attention on that line. But of course, you cant use markdown inside of a code block!

That could really be anything: the ability to make a line bold, or a different color, or put a little arrow outside the left margin of that line. Anything to focus attention to certain lines.

Answer (score 8):

Besides that *just typo* questions should be flagged rather than answered, you can always (almost?) use (language specific) comments to highlight your code changes:

> Ah, just a typo. You meant:
>
> ```html
> <html><!-- <<<<<<<<< <htwl> is mistyped -->
>     <body>
>         document
>     </body>
> </html>
> ```

Not only that's more natural to read for programmers familiar with a specific programming or markup language, and seen out in the wild<sup>1</sup>, it's also not worth putting efforts on such a feature IMO.

---

<sup>1)</sup>
<sub>**Typical example (C++):**</sub>

```c++
i += 10; // 08/11/2017, GMA fixed typo: i =+ 10;
```

Comment: I get what you're saying, but if the original example already has a lot of comments (which is common) then it can be hard to see the new comments.

Comment: @brentonstrine _"but if the original example already has a lot of comments ..."_ I'd rip out anything irrelevant from my answer code anyways. If you need a [MCVE] refer to some online compiler or use an external runnable snippet.

Comment: @user0042 _"Not only that's more natural ..."_ That deserves an upvote.